# Integration, try to find the expression of an integration in terms of f(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is :
[image]

For this question, I do not even know where to start with. I tried to integrate the whole identity but I don't know how to integrate the last bit. I am confused.

Comment: Please show the courtesy of transcribing the task description, mathjax/LaTeX makes that really simple. And add your own ideas on the solution. How would the equation change if you replace $x$ with $-x$?

Answer (score 5):

You have the following for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Denote by $K$ the integral you want to compute: $$6+f(x)-2f(-x)=3x^{2}K$$ and by replacing $x$ by $-x$, you get $$6+f(-x)-2f(x)=3x^{2}K,$$ so that $$18-3f(x)=9x^{2}K\ and\ 18-3f(-x)=9x^{2}K,$$ hence $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

We have, by replacing $f(-x)$ by $f(x)$ in the original equation: $6-f(x)=3x^{2}K$, so that $$f(x)=-3x^{2}K+6$$ and by integrating $f(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$, we get $$K=\int_{-1}^{1}(6-3x^{2}K)\text{d}x=12-2K,$$ hence $K=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $I=\int_{-1}^1f(t)dt$, $e(x)=(f(x)+f(-x))/2$ and $o(x)=(f(x)-f(-x))/2$ the even and odd parts of $f$ we have obviously $f=o+e$

$$\forall x\, 6+f(x)=2f(-x)+3Ix^2$$

Substitute $x\to -x$ we get

$$\forall x\, 6+f(-x)=2f(x)+3Ix^2$$

Adding and substructing the two identities we have

$$12+2e(x)=4e(x)+6Ix^2$$
$$-2o(x)=4o(x)$$

This means $o(x)=0$ and $f=e$ and our identity rewrites as

$$f(x)=6-6x^2\int_{0}^1f(t)dt$$

So $f$ is degree two polynomial of the form $f(x)=6-6ax^2$ ans so $\int_{0}^1f(t)dt=6-2a=a$ ans therefore $a=2$ and $I=2a=4$

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $I=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\mathrm dt$. Integrate the equation between $-1$ and $1$. This gives
$$\int_{-1}^1 (6+f(x))\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^12f(-x)\mathrm dx+I\int_{-1}^13x^2\mathrm dx.$$
Make the change of variable $x\to(-y)$ in the first integral of the right-hand side, which is then equal to $2I$. You get $ 12+I =2I+2I$ and thus $$I=4.$$